# JQuery Datepicker not getting set after post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code running in a MVC 4 partial page.  When ever I click a button that calls a javascript function that executes a post, my jquery datepicker gets cleared.  When I click the edit or cancel edit button, which don't do a post, then the datepicker gets setup correctly.  What needs to happen after the post for this to work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ResetDatePicker() {
        $(".datefield").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }

    function ShowEditHoliday(par) {
        $("#lblHolidayObserved-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#txtHolidayObserved-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#lblDateObserved-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#txtDateObserved-" + par).attr("class", "visible datefield");
        $("#btnEdit-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#btnSave-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#btnCancel-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#btnDelete-" + par).attr("class", "hide");

        ResetDatePicker();
    }

    function SaveEditHoliday(par) {
        var _holidayobserved = $("#txtHolidayObserved-" + par).val();
        var _dateobserved = $("#txtDateObserved-" + par).val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("SaveEditHoliday", "Routing")';
        $.post(url, { HolidayId: par, holidayobserved: _holidayobserved, dateobserved: _dateobserved },
            function (data) {
                $("#divHolidays").html(data);
            });

            ResetDatePicker();
    }

    function CancelEditHoliday(par) {
        $("#lblHolidayObserved-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#txtHolidayObserved-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#lblDateObserved-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#txtDateObserved-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#btnEdit-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
        $("#btnSave-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#btnCancel-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
        $("#btnDelete-" + par).attr("class", "visible");

        ResetDatePicker();
    }

    function DeleteHoliday(par) {
        var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteHoliday", "Routing")';
        $.post(url, { HolidayId: par },
            function (data) {
                $("#divHolidays").html(data);
            });

            ResetDatePicker();
        }

    function CreateHoliday() {
        var _holidayobserved = $("#txtHolidayObserved").val();
        var _dateobserved = $("#txtDateObserved").val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("CreateHoliday", "Routing")';
        $.post(url, { holidayobserved: _holidayobserved, dateobserved: _dateobserved },
            function (data) {
                $("#divHolidays").html(data);
            });

        ResetDatePicker();
    } 
</script>

<div id="divHolidays">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HolidayObserved)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateObserved)
            </th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="btnDelete-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="visible" onclick="DeleteHoliday(@item.HolidayId); return false;">
                    <img src="../../Images/delete_16x16.gif" alt="" />
                </button>
                <button id="btnEdit-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="visible" onclick="ShowEditHoliday(@item.HolidayId); return false;">
                    <img src="../../Images/edit_16x16.gif" alt="" />
                </button>
                <button id="btnSave-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="hide" onclick="SaveEditHoliday(@item.HolidayId); return false;">
                    <img src="../../Images/save_16x16.gif" alt="" />
                </button>
                <button id="btnCancel-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="hide" onclick="CancelEditHoliday(@item.HolidayId); return false;">
                    <img src="../../Images/cancel_16x16.gif" alt="" />
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label id="lblHolidayObserved-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="visible">@item.HolidayObserved.ToString()</label>
                <input id="txtHolidayObserved-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value="@item.HolidayObserved.ToString()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label id="lblDateObserved-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" class="visible">@item.DateObserved.ToShortDateString()</label>
                <input id="txtDateObserved-@item.HolidayId.ToString()" type="text" class="hide datefield" value="@item.DateObserved.ToShortDateString()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
    <br />
    <h3>New Holiday: </h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Holiday Observed: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtHolidayObserved"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date Observed: </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtDateObserved" class="datefield"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
                <button id="btnSaveNew" class="visible" onclick="CreateHoliday(); return false;">
                    <img src="../../Images/add_16x16.gif" alt="" />
                </button>        
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: how is you'r ajax call looks like? where is the section that been rendered after the ajax?

Comment: divHolidays is the section that is rendered after the $.post call.

Comment: any chance that you dont set the model on serverside while doing the post? - if the div do render again and the model isn't save his values than this what happend.

Comment: The model is set on the serverside while doing the post.